# Can we create a GRPC server in PHP instead of NodeJS?

Tags: php, grpc

I'm new to GRPC I read the quickstart guide and PHP basics. But I see lot all are using NodeJS to run the server side for grpc. But what I wanted to achieve is use PHP on both ends of grpc and create Server + Client in PHP only.

> So it's like Client will send the informtation to server and Server
>   will process the information realtime.

I have checked the test case files ServerTest.php code is below

```
class ServerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function testInvalidConstructor()
    {
        $server = new Grpc\Server('invalid_host');
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function testInvalidAddHttp2Port()
    {
        $this->server = new Grpc\Server([]);
        $this->port = $this->server->addHttp2Port(['0.0.0.0:0']);
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function testInvalidAddSecureHttp2Port()
    {
        $this->server = new Grpc\Server([]);
        $this->port = $this->server->addSecureHttp2Port(['0.0.0.0:0']);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible any help would be highly appriciated:

thanks

Comment: I think that with ReactPHP, Icicle or AMP this could be implemented but I'm just guessing since form what I've read the issue is keeping the connection open which these libraries should be able to do, I think-

Answer (score 6):

[roadrunner](https://github.com/spiral/roadrunner) may help. It's a golang frontend server with php worker pool.

Answer (score 5):

You can use gRPC PHP clients to connect to servers written in Node, Java, Python, or a number of other supported languages, but currently gRPC does not support writing PHP servers. The [gRPC PHP tutorial](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/php.html) describes how to set up a client.

There have been some discussions about implementing gRPC servers in PHP, e.g., the gRPC to FastCGI bridge mentioned [on the grpc-io mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/grpc-io/F3IyYaI_6S0/Cb55T92pBwAJ), but currently this is not supported in gRPC.

Answer (score 1):

https://roadrunner.dev/ is an application server for PHP that can allow you to achieve this.
I took some notes recently while setting it up and published those over there: https://dev.to/khepin/building-a-grpc-server-in-php-3bgc . Hope that helps though the answer comes a bit later after the question.

Answer (score 0):

as "Eric G" said currently php server not supported in gRPC.
here it is from the [Official gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php/#download-the-example) website:

> Note that currently you can only create clients in PHP for gRPC services - you can find out how to create gRPC servers in our other tutorials, e.g. Node.js.

you can use gRPC community projects like this:
https://github.com/spiral/php-grpc

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

what about this, The php grpc server framework with protobuf.

https://github.com/hetao29/php-grpc-server-protobuf

Answer (score -11):

> I'm not sure if this is possible

Read description of [gRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grpc) - `gRPC is a language neutral and platform neutral`

So yes, you can. [gRPC PHP tutorial](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/php.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only use PHP as a client at the moment. Hopefully the gRPC team will change their minds and support PHP on the server side.